# I'm creating a flipcard app and need assistance

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating a jQuery flashcard app.  I've got everything right except for the flipping part.  I'm not able to use plugins.  I've actually got half of the flipping part coded, but I can't figure out how to make the reverse side perform the rotation.  Here's the jQuery I have so far.

```
$('#pp1').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('flip');
    $(this).hide(1000, function(){
        $('#pp2').show();
    });
});
```

This shows the front of the card and flips the entire thing halfway, but doesn't continue the rotation with the back side showing.  Would I just need to do this function in reverse?  If not, does anyone have any ideas for what I need to do?

**CSS**

```
.flip{
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li><img id="pp1" src="GIII-Flashcards/Flashcard-JPGs/Flashcard-PP-1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img id="pp2" src="GIII-Flashcards/Flashcard-JPGs/Flashcard-PP-2.jpg" /></li>
```

Comment: Search Google for "css flip" for many tutorials and examples.

Comment: Fully related : https://www.google.ca/search?newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q="css+flip"+for+many+tutorials+and+examples  AND  https://www.google.ca/search?newwindow=1&q="css+flip"+stackoverflow&oq="css+flip"+stackoverflow

Comment: Awesome, thank you both very much.